# how to enhance this java class that reads xls file using POI and JXL?

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl

I am currently using POI to read excel file and it is working great except it can't read xls files with older format (BIFF5/ office 95) to resolve this I am catching OldExcelFormatException and in this case call a function that will read the xls file using jxl. What I want to achieve is to write the same code but without catching the exception. Here is the current working code:

```
public void translate() throws IOException, CmpException
{
  ArrayList<String> row = null;

  try
  {
    // create a new org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Filesystem
    POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(fin);
    w = new HSSFWorkbook(poifs);
  }
  catch (OldExcelFormatException e) // OldExcelFormatException
  {
    w = null;
    System.out.println("OldExcelFormatException");
    translateBIFF5();
  }
  catch (Exception e) // Any Exception
  {
    w = null; 
  }

  if (w != null)
  {
     // read the excel file using POI
  } 
}

private void translateBIFF5() throws IOException, CmpException
{
  ArrayList<String> row = null;
  try
  {
    jxl_w = Workbook.getWorkbook(excelFile);
  }
  catch (Exception e) // Any Exception
  {
    jxl_w = null; 
  }

  if (jxl_w != null)
  {
     // read the excel file using jxl
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys. I found the solution by myself. The trick is to see the workbook name: For excel 95/97, the workbook name is 'Book' while for the new format the workbook name is 'WorkBook'. So here is the piece of coding I have been searching for:

```
  POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(fin);

  DirectoryNode directory = poifs.getRoot();
  Iterator<Entry> i       = directory.getEntries();
  while (i.hasNext())
  {
    Entry e         = i.next();
    String bookName = e.getName();
    if (bookName.equals("Book"))
    {
      System.out.println("This is an old format");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("This is a new format");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Actually this code still have a bug, since I am iterating the entries, I will not be able to convert them to excel I have to re-iterate over them in some way